# Adding 'Select All' to a filter

Tags: php

I have successfully set up a filter for a calendar that displays the upcoming jobs for different users where you can choose the user you want to see the jobs for. Now, I want to add a 'select all' to the filter so that it shows the jobs for everyone rather than just the specified user.
I have done my research and found a similar question but it doesn't quite apply to my situation (that question used an input form field whereas mine uses the database to create the filter and so that response won't work for me), before I get my question marked as a duplicate which I don't believe it is. 
Here is the page code:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {
     $workDetails = GetWork($_REQUEST['id']);
     $accountName = $_REQUEST['accountname'];
     $accountId = $_REQUEST['accountid'];
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['inassigneduser'])){
     $inassigneduser = $_REQUEST['inassigneduser'];
}else{
     $inassigneduser = $_SESSION['userid'];
}

echo "<h2 class='title'>Planned Works</h2><hr class='red'/>";
?>
<table style="margin-bottom:10px;">
<tr>
<td style='width:120px;'><span class='title'>Assigned To:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> 
</td>
<td id="plannedworkusers" style='width:170px;text-align:left;'><?php echo 
GetUserCombo($inassigneduser, true, "inassigneduser","All");?></td><td 
style='text-align:left;'></td>
<td style='text-align:left;'><a href='#' class='button' 
name='filterassigneduser' >Filter</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
echo "<div id='calendar' style='float:left; width:100%; margin-left:10px;'> 
</div>";
$events = '';
$events = GetHolidaysForCal($inassigneduser);
```

And my functions.php file:

```
function GetHolidaysForCal($inassigneduser)
{
     mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
     mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die("Unable to select database");
     $eventArray = array();

     $sql = "SELECT w.*, c.name AS contactname, a.name AS accountname
        FROM works w, contact c, account a
        WHERE w.id = c.worksid
        AND w.accountid = a.id
        AND c.contacttype = 0
  AND w.assignedtouser = $inassigneduser
        AND (w.infracompletiondate != '0000-00-00'
                OR w.meteringcompletiondate != '0000-00-00'
                OR w.meterremovaldate != '0000-00-00'
                OR w.servicedisconnectiondate != '0000-00-00'
                OR w.gt1date != '0000-00-00'
                OR w.sitesurveydate != '0000-00-00'
                OR w.infrastructurestartdate != '0000-00-00'
      OR w.liveanddeadcheckdate != '0000-00-00')

        ORDER BY w.infracompletiondate ASC, w.meteringcompletiondate ASC ";
     $result = mysql_query($sql);
     $eventstr = "";
     $color = 'black';
```

I hope that will provide enough information, any help with how to add this 'select all' option would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'll try editing it...it is indented on my side. Don't judge me xD

Comment: You need to start looking at programs in pieces -- if you've seen a question that used form inputs instead of a database, all you need to figure out is how to get information from a database... Which has been answered many times on this very website. Your question provides too much unrelated information and is hard to read.

Comment: I know how to get the information from a database. As stated, my code works and now I'm looking for a way to improve it so that I can select all users.

Comment: Just hardcode an option with an empty value, and then have your WHERE clause only pull a specific ID if the selected value wasn't empty.

Comment: A couple of big issues: 1. **Don't use the old and insecure `mysql_*`-functions**. They have been completely removed in PHP 7.0. - 2. **Use prepared statements.** Your current code is **_wide open_** to SQL injections since your using completely unescaped user data directly in your query.

Comment: What happen if you remove `AND w.accountid = a.id` from your query?

Comment: Mawg, it stops the jobs from showing on the calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I finally managed to figure it out on my own. Below is the code for my functions.php file which I edited.

```
$sql = "SELECT w.*, c.name AS contactname, a.name AS accountname
        FROM works w, contact c, account a
        WHERE w.id = c.worksid
        AND w.accountid = a.id
        AND c.contacttype = 0";

 //Added code
  if ($inassigneduser != "all") {
    $sql .= " AND w.assignedtouser = " . $inassigneduser;
  }

        $sql .= " AND (w.infracompletiondate != '0000-00-00'
                OR w.meteringcompletiondate != '0000-00-00'
                OR w.meterremovaldate != '0000-00-00'
                OR w.servicedisconnectiondate != '0000-00-00'
                OR w.gt1date != '0000-00-00'
                OR w.sitesurveydate != '0000-00-00'
                OR w.infrastructurestartdate != '0000-00-00'
      OR w.liveanddeadcheckdate != '0000-00-00')

        ORDER BY w.infracompletiondate ASC, w.meteringcompletiondate ASC ";
```